# perl Break file into chunks or pieces

Tags: perl

I have a large file consisting of several lines. I need to break the file into chunks based on size(say 1 file in to 4 parts), but i need no line to be broken in 2 parts(each line should be fully present in a chunk) and then have that chunks given to each thread to process and after processing i will then again reassemble all the chunks.
Mainly i want to reduce the processing time of file contents(i do some replacement in the text of file).

What would be the best approach to solve this problem?.
What i have in mind is to reach till the end byte of chunk based on size, if the end character is not end of line go on reading till i get the end of line and have that part stored.

Any suggestions or better algo on the same. 
Appreciate your help.

EDIt:

Also the whole contents are in a variable, how can i reach to certain byte in a variable?

EDIT:
As suggested by users, one more edit with proper English and problem statement:

Problem Statement:

I have a some data(whole html page contents) in a variable(scalar) in perl assume $str, the data consists of several lines(approx 1762899 lines)
I need to have that data in scalar be divided into smaller chunks(having some lines from original) based on some length like $str1, $str2, $str3, $str4 in a way if i join these var i get the full contents.

Requirement:

I need the above strs, so i can give them to threads and after all threads done, i will join all these to get the whole contents back.

my understanding:

I will use substr to get data from a char to char but agin i need to make sure that the last char i get in substr is new line character. How to approach in this case?

Solution needed please. Thanks.

Comment: I think I would do it the other way around, break the file up in an array with lines and add them together again to create chunks of the required size

Comment: but in that i will have to first split and have all stored in array. I also need to run a function in thread passing the chunk. How will i do that for array, passing each array element?

Comment: what you mean by whole contents in a variable? You can use **split** to split your large file.

Comment: like whole file contents are in a var and now i have to divide in to smaller parts each bar holding them. Split can split at a pattern but i need to split at certain length.

Comment: You have paraphrased the appearance of the file in vague English prose, therefore you also only get vague answers. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10732552/edit) to improve it: post the concrete file, point out the places where you want to break it into chunks.

Comment: Unless your processing is something trivial, it is unlikely to be possible to process HTML in arbitrary chunks. If it is well-formed XHTML then I suggest using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) to split it into *functional* chunks and serve the processing using these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use this algorithm to split the source HTML into a number of fairly equal parts, split on line boundaries.

I am still concerned that your processing may not be possible with such arbitrarily-split data, but if you have problems you must ask again.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $html;
$html .= $_ x 10 . "\n" for 'A' .. 'Z';

use constant PARTITIONS => 4;

my @start;
push @start, $-[0] while $html =~ /^/gm;
push @start, length $html;
my $n = @start;
my @parts = map $start[$_ * ($n-1) / PARTITIONS], 0 .. PARTITIONS;

for my $i (0 .. $#parts-1) {
  my ($start, $size) = ($parts[$i], $parts[$i+1] - $parts[$i]);
  print substr $html, $start, $size;
  print '-' x 10 . "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEE
FFFFFFFFFF
----------
GGGGGGGGGG
HHHHHHHHHH
IIIIIIIIII
JJJJJJJJJJ
KKKKKKKKKK
LLLLLLLLLL
MMMMMMMMMM
----------
NNNNNNNNNN
OOOOOOOOOO
PPPPPPPPPP
QQQQQQQQQQ
RRRRRRRRRR
SSSSSSSSSS
----------
TTTTTTTTTT
UUUUUUUUUU
VVVVVVVVVV
WWWWWWWWWW
XXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZZZZ
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive (but maybe efficient enough) solution:

Fork 4 child processes, read the input file line by line and send each line to a child process.  Tell the child process which filename to use for the output.

When the work is done the parent process can aggregate the results again.

Comment: great thought, but how i make sure that the data is in serial order as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough for me. Still some suggestions.

You could use standard unix tools like `split --lines=10000`.

If you need to use perl, you can split through `while`, based on :

```
open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt")
                       or die "cannot open < input.txt: $!";
while ( <$fh> ) {
    # controll count of lines you need and open/close new FH if needed...
    print $nfh $_;
}
close($fh);
```

About your EDIT: do you need reach to byte or char? Your question is about text and strings, so i assume you need chars. Then you can use `substr`.

Comment: substr is nice option, why i didnt thought in that way.
Suppose my var has 1000 chars and substr 250, i need to make sure the 250th char is eol or new line character, how i do that. I will have to loop till i get the new line char, is it efficient? or any other option?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to come up with a code to solve it.
Please find the code below.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;

    ### File contents to be broken in pieces ###
    open(FH, "<index.html");

    ### slurp whole file in scalar ###
    my $text = do { local $/; <FH> };

    ### Length of file ###
    my $length = length $text;
    print "length=$length\n";

    #### We will create 6 threads so divide it into 6 parts ###
    my $chunk_sz = int($length/6);
    print "chunk size=$chunk_sz\n";

    ### Lets have the chunks into some var and check the chunk end with proper new line char ###
    my $start = 0;
    my @res;

    for(my $i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++)
    {
        #print "start is : $start\n";
        my $chunk;
        my $var = 0;

        ### If it's last chunk, take all contents ###
        if($i == 5)
        {
            $chunk_sz = $length - $start;
            $chunk = substr($text, $start, $chunk_sz);
        }
        else
        {
            $chunk = substr($text, $start, $chunk_sz);
        }
        START:
        my $last_ch = chop($chunk);    ### If last char is not new line(\n) char find it and save the chunk ###

    while($last_ch !~ /\n/ && $i != 5)
    {
        $var += 1;
        $chunk = substr($text, $start, $chunk_sz+$var);
        goto START;
    }
    ### Start from the last chunk char + 1 ###
    $start += $chunk_sz+$var+1;
    $res[$i] = $chunk."\n";
}

## Further code to process the chunk in threads goes here ###
```

Any suggestions for improvement or corrections?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be useful to this user here but I was looking for perl code that will break a million line file into multiple files of 100K lines each. After reading multiple posts and trial and error I got this code to share. Thumbs up if you likey!

```
#!/bin/perl -s
#
# $Header$
# $Log$
use File::Basename;
use File::stat;
use English;
use Time::Local;
use Data::Dumper;
use IO::Handle;
use Fcntl;                             # For O_RDWR, O_CREAT, etc.
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use bigint;
use strict;

$\ = "\n";    # set output record separator

print "Starting program ...";



#
#  Get the interface directory path
#
my $ScriptName = $0;
my $ScriptDirPath = `dirname $ScriptName`;
chop($ScriptDirPath);


my $LOAD_INP_FILE = $ScriptDirPath . "03g_loadInp.txt";
my $LOAD_CHUNK_FILE = $ScriptDirPath . "04g_loadInp_00000000.txt";

my $source = $LOAD_INP_FILE;
my $lines_per_file = 100000;

open (my $FH, "<$source") or die "Could not open source file. $!";
open (my $OUT, ">$LOAD_CHUNK_FILE") or die "Could not open destination fil
+e. $!";

#this is line counter
my $i = 0;

print "Creating new $LOAD_CHUNK_FILE ...";

my $line;
while ($line = <$FH> ) {
    chop $line;
    print $OUT $line;
    $i++;

    if ($i % $lines_per_file == 0) {
        close($OUT);
        my $FHNEW = sprintf("%08d", $i);
        my $LOAD_CHUNK_FILE_NEW = $ScriptDirPath . "04g_loadInp_${FHNEW}.txt";
        open ($OUT, ">$LOAD_CHUNK_FILE_NEW") or die "Could not open destinatio
+n file. $!";
        print "Creating new $LOAD_CHUNK_FILE_NEW ...";
    }
}


print "Ending program ...";
exit 0;

#
#  End of Main Program
#
```